# Next.js Redirect from dashboard / to login page if the token is not existed

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

I'm new in Next.js and I'm wondering how to redirect from dashboard page to Login page if the userToken is not existed.

in reactjs I do it simplay like below mentioned at the end, when I try it with nextjs render me the below error.
When I try to access the dashboard it give me the first a quck flash look of dashboard and then redirect me to the log-in form which I don't want that flash look I just want it to redirect the user to log-ing page without any delay or any flash look of dashboard or any other page.

**Error in the console is like belwo**

> xt-dev.js:23 Warning: Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute
> `raised`.>
> If you want to write it to the DOM, pass a string instead:
> raised="true" or raised={value.toString()}.
> at button
> at form
> at div
> at div
> at div
> at LoginPage (webpack-internal:///./pages/auth/login/index.jsx:37:128)
> at LayoutProvider (webpack-internal:///./layout/context/layoutcontext.js:16:

**I have tried the below code**

```
  useEffect(() => {
        if (!userToken) {
            return router?.push("/auth/login");
        }
    });
```

In react js I tried this it worked perfectly

```
if (!userToken) {
    return <Navigate to="/auth/login" />;
  }
```

**but When I try this in nextjs it give me the below error**
`import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";`

> Error:  may be used only in the context of a 
> component.

Answer (score 0):

In Nextjs you should use:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
const router = useRouter();
```

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router

Comment: it does'nt work

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
import router from "next/router";
router.push("/");
```